# I want my button at a specific part of my webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a `CommandButton` in a `UI:Repeat` and I always want that button to be in the same Spot behind an entry.

At the moment it looks like this 
[image: My WebsiteLayout]

But I want the green and red buttons in a straight vertical light!

[image: My desired Layout]

```
<ui:repeat value="#{zipCodeListView.getAllZipCodeDTO()}" var="allZipCodeDTO">

                <div class="flex-horizontal">
                    <div><p> #{allZipCodeDTO.favouriteZipCode}, #{allZipCodeDTO.cityName} </p></div>
                <!-- Button für das Löschen des Eintrags -->
                    <div> <p:link value="Bearbeiten" styleClass="btn-success btn-block widthAuto"
                                        style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px ;" icon="fa fa-refresh"
                                        includeViewParams="true"
                                        outcome="edit">  
                                    <f:param name="id" value="#{allZipCodeDTO.id}"/></p:link></div>
                    <div> <p:commandButton styleClass="btn-danger fixed-button-edit" value="Löschen" icon="fa fa-close"
                                             immediate="true"
                                             action="#{zipCodeView.deleteEntry(allZipCodeDTO)}"/></div></div>


                </ui:repeat>
```

My CSS

```
.flex-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The other CSS is from a primefaces skin!

```
<ul class="box margin-top-left">

                <div class="flex-horizontal">
                    <div><p> 85049, Ingolstadt </p></div>

                    <div><a href="/zipcode/edit.xhtml?id=1005&amp;jfwid=EC7AF8F994C189FA9CBCA53840270782:0" class="ui-link ui-widget btn-success btn-block widthAuto" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px ;">Bearbeiten</a></div>
                    <div><button id="j_idt32:j_idt36:0:j_idt40" name="j_idt32:j_idt36:0:j_idt40" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left btn-danger fixed-button-edit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt32:j_idt36:0:j_idt40&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Löschen</span></button></div></div>

                <div class="flex-horizontal">
                    <div><p> 85000, München </p></div>

                    <div><a href="/zipcode/edit.xhtml?id=1002&amp;jfwid=EC7AF8F994C189FA9CBCA53840270782:0" class="ui-link ui-widget btn-success btn-block widthAuto" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px ;">Bearbeiten</a></div>
                    <div><button id="j_idt32:j_idt36:1:j_idt40" name="j_idt32:j_idt36:1:j_idt40" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left btn-danger fixed-button-edit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt32:j_idt36:1:j_idt40&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Löschen</span></button></div></div>

                <div class="flex-horizontal">
                    <div><p> 12333, Hallo Noii </p></div>

                    <div><a href="/zipcode/edit.xhtml?id=1024&amp;jfwid=EC7AF8F994C189FA9CBCA53840270782:0" class="ui-link ui-widget btn-success btn-block widthAuto" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px ;">Bearbeiten</a></div>
                    <div><button id="j_idt32:j_idt36:2:j_idt40" name="j_idt32:j_idt36:2:j_idt40" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left btn-danger fixed-button-edit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt32:j_idt36:2:j_idt40&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Löschen</span></button></div></div>

                <div class="flex-horizontal">
                    <div><p> 89458, 789 </p></div>

                    <div><a href="/zipcode/edit.xhtml?id=1021&amp;jfwid=EC7AF8F994C189FA9CBCA53840270782:0" class="ui-link ui-widget btn-success btn-block widthAuto" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px ;">Bearbeiten</a></div>
                    <div><button id="j_idt32:j_idt36:3:j_idt40" name="j_idt32:j_idt36:3:j_idt40" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left btn-danger fixed-button-edit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt32:j_idt36:3:j_idt40&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Löschen</span></button></div></div>

                <div class="flex-horizontal">
                    <div><p> 78945, 4 </p></div>

                    <div><a href="/zipcode/edit.xhtml?id=1022&amp;jfwid=EC7AF8F994C189FA9CBCA53840270782:0" class="ui-link ui-widget btn-success btn-block widthAuto" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px ;">Bearbeiten</a></div>
                    <div><button id="j_idt32:j_idt36:4:j_idt40" name="j_idt32:j_idt36:4:j_idt40" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left btn-danger fixed-button-edit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt32:j_idt36:4:j_idt40&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Löschen</span></button></div></div>

                <div class="flex-horizontal">
                    <div><p> 12345, 1111111111107 </p></div>

                    <div><a href="/zipcode/edit.xhtml?id=1023&amp;jfwid=EC7AF8F994C189FA9CBCA53840270782:0" class="ui-link ui-widget btn-success btn-block widthAuto" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px ;">Bearbeiten</a></div>
                    <div><button id="j_idt32:j_idt36:5:j_idt40" name="j_idt32:j_idt36:5:j_idt40" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left btn-danger fixed-button-edit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt32:j_idt36:5:j_idt40&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Löschen</span></button></div></div>
            </ul>
```

Generated HTML

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Comment: can you provide generated html..? using view soruce..

Comment: @Nico try this `justify-content:flex-end'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?
By the way, your HTML's structure has a problem since right inside `<ul>` must be `<li>`, in my example code below, you can change `width` of `.r1, .r2, .r3, .bt1, .bt2` depend on your design

```css
ul{
  max-width: 700px;
}
.r1{
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r2, .r3{
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bt1{
  background-color: green;
}

.bt2{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="r1">Row 1</div>
    <div class="r2"><button class="bt1">1 Row 1</button></div>
    <div class="r3"><button class="bt2">2 Row 1</button></div>
  </li>
   <li>
    <div class="r1">Example Row 2</div>
    <div class="r2"><button class="bt1">1 Row 1</button></div>
    <div class="r3"><button class="bt2">2 Row 1</button></div>
  </li>
   <li>
    <div class="r1">A Long text</div>
    <div class="r2"><button class="bt1">1 Row 1</button></div>
    <div class="r3"><button class="bt2">2 Row 1</button></div>
  </li>
   <li>
    <div class="r1">Row i don't</div>
    <div class="r2"><button class="bt1">1 Row 1</button></div>
    <div class="r3"><button class="bt2">2 Row 1</button></div>
  </li>
   <li>
    <div class="r1">Row test</div>
    <div class="r2"><button class="bt1">1 Row 1</button></div>
    <div class="r3"><button class="bt2">2 Row 1</button></div>
  </li>
   <li>
    <div class="r1">Row 1</div>
    <div class="r2"><button class="bt1">1 Row 1</button></div>
    <div class="r3"><button class="bt2">2 Row 1</button></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think so, when the left text increases, it will fall down in the right way. I tried your code, it will lead to a problem when left text increase, try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code structure, I think this will help you.

```css
.flex-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    max-width: 600px;
}
.button-box {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    margin-left: auto;
}

a.ui-link.ui-widget {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="box margin-top-left">

        <div class="flex-horizontal">
            <div><p> 85049, Ingolstadt </p></div>
            <div class="button-box">
                <div><a href="/zipcode/edit.xhtml?id=1005&amp;jfwid=EC7AF8F994C189FA9CBCA53840270782:0" class="ui-link ui-widget btn-success btn-block widthAuto" style="">Bearbeiten</a></div>
                <div><button id="j_idt32:j_idt36:0:j_idt40" name="j_idt32:j_idt36:0:j_idt40" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left btn-danger fixed-button-edit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt32:j_idt36:0:j_idt40&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Löschen</span></button></div>
            </div>
            </div>


        <div class="flex-horizontal">
            <div><p> 85000, Münchensd sd fsdfsdfsdfsdf </p></div>
            <div class="button-box">
                <div><a href="/zipcode/edit.xhtml?id=1002&amp;jfwid=EC7AF8F994C189FA9CBCA53840270782:0" class="ui-link ui-widget btn-success btn-block widthAuto" style="">Bearbeiten</a></div>
                <div><button id="j_idt32:j_idt36:1:j_idt40" name="j_idt32:j_idt36:1:j_idt40" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left btn-danger fixed-button-edit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;j_idt32:j_idt36:1:j_idt40&quot;});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-close"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Löschen</span></button></div>
            
            </div>
            </div>


  
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you :) 
Could you briefly explain what you did?

Comment: I Updated both button in a new div.. and also removed first button margin..

Comment: Actually, there's a HTML's structure problem since right inside <ul> must be <li>, not a <div>